# Adding Spring bean using annotations : placing it & initializing properties values

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I've gleaned that adding the context:component-scan will enable adding any jar with bean annotated as @Bean to the spring configuration, but , while getting lost in the Framework reference...

- How can I add that bean as interceptor on specific channel?
- How can bean properties be initialized if there's no  element in the context.xml to specify them ? (such as String properties)

Thanks to all ....
(it's spring framework 3.0.)

Comment: What do you mean by "specific channel"?

Comment: there are channels defined in the spring.xml such as inbound channel data channel etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `@Value` annotation to inject the value from a property coming from a property file or a -Dproperty

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.html#new-java-configuration

Comment: Ouch. Just saw that it's a new feature of 3.0.4.. Will see whether upgrade is an easy option. Thanks anyway though!